# Conditional block error in ruby

Tags: ruby, operator-precedence

Given that this part of code works,

```
if @sprint.nil?
  redirect_to sprints_path
else
  @sprint.define_state
end
```

I don't understand why this part of code doesn't:

```
@sprint.nil? ? redirect_to sprints_path : @sprint.define_state
```

I don't know why in the second example the program goes immediately into the `else` block. Could someone explain how it is possible?

Comment: You are missing parentheses `@sprint.nil? ? redirect_to(sprints_path) : @sprint.define_state` since the original is on multiple lines the parentheses can be omitted but the ternary version will require them for the code to be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Using headings, such as "Situation:" and "Question:" aren't particularly desirable. While it might seem to help, Stack Overflow aims to be like a cookbook of programming problems and answer, a slightly informal version of a reference book. As such, write a clearly thought-out question in a concise manner and you'll do well.

Comment: It's not idiomatic, and not recommended, that you use ternary statements like `@sprint.nil? ? redirect_to sprints_path : @sprint.define_state
` for flow control. Returning values is great but `redirect_to sprints_path` looks like a change in flow. I'd recommend sticking with the `if` version.

Comment: Oh sorry and thanks. I would be more carefull

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find an explicit documentation, but presumably, the ternary operator `?` `:` has higher precedence than passing an argument to a method. That makes your example be parsed as:

```
@sprint.nil? ? (redirect_to sprints_path : @sprint.define_state)
```

with `:` appearing in an inappropriate position, missing a `?`. (Notice that the error is not caused by `?` missing a `:` because that part lays outside of the offending `:`, latter of which primarily raises a syntax error, and blocks the syntax error that would be raised by the former.)